# Modified date of Records in Data extension using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

I want to fetch the date when a data extension record was modified . I want to exclude all the records modified in last 15 days or  DE itself if any of its record has been modified in last 15 days. I know this can be achieved using WS proxy SSJS but i am unable to find anything prudctive in SF documentation . I have also gone through Data extension Object properties . Can anyone help me with that how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a „last modified date” field in your DE?

Comment: No , I want to fetch it from DataExtensionObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you won't be able to retroactively extract this data even using WSProxy.

Let's assume you have a data extension called `WSProxyDE` with two columns:

- `TextID` - your primary key
- `NumberValue` - a numeric value you update

Insert data into this DE and modify one row (let's say the last of 3 rows).

Run the script on CloudPage:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

var deName = "WSProxyDE"; //The name of your DE
var cols = ["TextId", "NumberValue"]; // columns you want to retrieve

var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var object = "DataExtensionObject[dekey]".replace("dekey", deName);
var data = proxy.retrieve(object, cols);

Write(Stringify(data.Results));
</script>
```

You will get a response in the form of a stringifed array, but if you extract the third object representing your updated row, you will get this:

```
{
       "Name":null,
       "Keys":null,
       "Type":"DataExtensionObject",
       "Properties":[
          {
             "Name":"TextId",
             "Value":"ThirdContact"
          },
          {
             "Name":"NumberValue",
             "Value":"3"
          }
       ],
       "Client":null,
       "PartnerKey":null,
       "PartnerProperties":null,
       "CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000",
       "ModifiedDate":null,
       "ID":0,
       "ObjectID":null,
       "CustomerKey":null,
       "Owner":null,
       "CorrelationID":null,
       "ObjectState":null,
       "IsPlatformObject":false
    }
```

The value you're seeking - `ModifiedDate` - is null (and the CreatedDateValue is also useless).

To achieve this you would need a column where you could store the date when a record was modified, but I see no way of extracting this data for that's already in your DE and was modified before you introduce a new column storing the modification date.

Comment: I have gone through SF Documentation on Dataextension object .The DataExtensionObject object represents a row within a data extension. And has column ModifiedDate Nullable` which Indicates the last time object information was modified. I want to fetch this field by passing customer key in filter in retrieve function.

Doc Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionobject.htm

Comment: I know the field is mentioned in the documentation and is returned by the API call I posted above, but the value is null even if the row was modified. Try my solution and see for yourself - the code will retrieve  rows from a data extension, but the ModifiedDate value will not be populated.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataExtensionObject` has a `ModifiedDate` and while the documentation states it is for an individual record, this seems not to be allowed to retrieve.

If you use `describe` you can see that `ModifiedDate` is no retrievable

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
    var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var data = proxy.describe('DataExtensionObject');
    Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

**Output**

```
9:
    AttributeMaps: null
    Client: null
    CorrelationID: null
    CreatedDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000"
    CustomerKey: null
    DataType: "DateTime"
    DefaultValue: null
    Description: null
    DisplayOrder: 0
    ID: 0
    IsAccountProperty: false
    IsContextSpecific: false
    IsCreatable: false
    IsEditable: false
    IsFilterable: false
    IsNillable: false
    IsPartnerProperty: false
    IsPlatformObject: false
    IsQueryable: false
    IsRequired: false
    IsRestrictedPicklist: false
    IsRetrievable: false
    IsSendTime: false
    IsUpdatable: true
    IsViewable: false
    Label: null
    Markups: null
    MaxLength: 0
    MaxValue: null
    MinLength: 0
    MinValue: null
    ModifiedDate: null
    Name: "ModifiedDate"
    ObjectID: null
    ObjectState: null
    Owner: null
    PartnerKey: null
    PartnerMap: null
    PartnerProperties: null
    PicklistItems: null
    Precision: 0
    PropertyType: "string"
    References: null
    RelationshipName: null
    Scale: 0
    Status: null
    ValueType: "xsdstring"
```

As the `ModifiedDate` of the `DataExtensionObject` is not retrievable, it seems you cannot get the `ModifiedDate` for an individual record.